# IOT Kura Installation unable to fetch from git hub repo and Repo Not Found

Tags: eclipse, git, kura

Currently I'm facing an issue while installing Kura using Eclipse Installer.

Attached the screenshot and log for further reference.

I hope the issue is unable to pull from git repo.

Could somebody help me out and let me know in case of any further details required.

[image]

[image]

**UPDATED as on 03-09-2017**

Now the issue is different attached the screenshot for your reference and when I click back the git repo is not found .

I trying to setup more than a month but still couldn't it what is the other way to explore Kura.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From this [eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492527), this is more likely related to a network issue.

> It seems the session has been dropped in making a channel connection.
>
> > |And most important: How can we avoid this?
>
> There must be many reasons for unexpected session drops caused by
>   external factors, so I suggest to re-try making sessions or channels
>   at such a case.

If that persists, try and use https url:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git@
```

---

The error message seen looks like [JGit issue 455005](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455005):

```
java.io.IOException: Could not delete file C:\path\to\repo\.git\objects\pack\pack-5cb....pack
```

> That's a common problem on Windows systems. As soon as you open a repository and do operations which access the packfiles (nearly all git operations do that: staging view, history ...) JGit caches data from the packfiles and keeps handles to packfiles open. But as long as handles are open you cannot delete the file under windows.
>
> On Unix systems you don't have this problem because you can unlink files on which you have open file handles. The root cause for your problem is that we delete the repo only halfways. Aftwards we have a corrupted nearly empty gitdir and that reflog doesn't work on that is only the smallest of all problems.

check if the issue persists after a reboot (to make sure there is no other process preempts the file).
If not, try deleting fully (with Eclipse closed), and try again to clone it.

See also [bug 336800](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=336800):

> You are creating a new Git object that has a repository associated with it.
>   This repository is automatically opened and thus has to be closed so that file resources are released.

Comment: Can I just run the above command in git bash that would be enough? Ok If I use the above one will it affect for all URL connection.

Comment: @Arun Yesn that would switch all ssh URL to https, but this is just for testing. Once you are done with the test, you can edit ~/.gitconfig and remove the setting.

Comment: the above issue has been solved but even for this do we need to retry again and again

Comment: No it is not solved still now. I asked as a question

Comment: First issue has been solved by the repeating again and again. But now I'm facing another issue . I have given the update log information.